# Facebook Session object has "email" permission but Request.executeMeRequestAsync(...) returns no email

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I'm rewriting an app to include Facebook login and I would like to get the user's email address.  I have requested the permission in the `Session` object and scrutinizing it I can see that it does have this permission.  However, when I call

```
Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, this);
```

from the `StatusCallback#call(...)` method (the parent `Activity` implements this and other callbacks) I don't get an email address.

```
@Override
public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
    Object emailObject = user.asMap().get("email"); //this is null
    //...
}
```

Moreover, calling

```
Request.executeGraphPathRequestAsync(session, "me?fields=email", this);
```

gives me an OAuthException, though I'm using the same `Session` that successfully gets the user.

I've checked `Session#getPermissions()` and I *do* have the email permission.  Why aren't I getting email?

Comment: I attempted to set read permissions like this : `authButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));` and then tried to access the email like this `user.asMap().get("email")` but it always returns `null`.

Comment: It may be because the user hasn't set a default email address (so all users have email addresses but this function returns the default).  See my answer :)

Comment: The radio button was checked but I went ahead and created another email anyway and the new email was saved as the primary email.  And only after that was I able to access the email through `user.asMap().get("email")`.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is described here:

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/482815835078469/

and one of the commenters, Mai Khánh, writes:

> I found why this happened, please thumbs up so that support team can be noticed.
>
> 1/ Go to this link: https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=account&section=email&view.
>
> 2/ Look at Primary email editing form, if the radio button isn't checked by default, the bug will appear.
>
> I think this is cause by facebook system sometime confusing when a facebook account has more than 1 email.
>
> My temp solution: Add more random email to that account -> the form will ask you to select primary email -> choose primary email -> fill in passwork, then submit -> done.
>
> The point is if you just check primary account without adding another random email, when everything done then you get back -> the edit form still not checked any primary email.

This worked.  It's a Facebook bug.